# Preventing pam_authenticate() from prompting for a password

Tags: authentication, pam

I am working on a Linux application (my_app) that will require RADIUS authentication to be used. I am planning to use the PAM framework for this. I am a complete rookie when it comes to PAM, which is what is bringing me to this forum.

With the goal above in mind I have a PAM policy file named my_app under /etc/pam.d, with the following contents:

```
   auth sufficient /lib64/security/pam_radius_auth.so
```

(more lines will be present here eventually, but for the purposes of my question they are not relevant.)

Within my_app I first invoked pam_start() and and then pam_authenticate(). On invoking the latter I am presented with a password prompt, and on typing in the correct password the authentication succeeds, as expected.

The thing is, the way my_app is supposed to work no password prompts are acceptable. In essence, my_app will get the password by means that are not relevant to this discussion which it will then provide to the PAM framework (together with a user name) for pam_radius_auth.so to carry out the authentication.

With this in mind, how can I prevent pam_authenticate() from prompting for a password? My first thought was to invoke pam_set_item(), before invoking pam_authenticate(), as follows:

```
    pam_set_item(handle, PAM_AUTHTOK, password)
```

but this does not work: it always returns PAM_BAD_ITEM. My guess is that pam_radius_auth.so is getting in the way here somehow, but I am not sure about the actual mechanism that is making this happen - I was under the impression that, with the PAM policy file above, pam_radius_auth.so would only kick in when invoking pam_authenticate().

I would be grateful if any PAM experts could throw some light into what may be going on here, with the understanding that my ultimate goal is to prevent pam_authenticate() from prompting me for a password.

Comment: Well, I found out how to prevent pam_authenticate() from prompting for a password - it amounts to changing the PAM policy for the application as follows:
`auth sufficient /lib64/security/pam_radius_auth.so skip_passwd`. pam_set_item() is still failing as described though.

Comment: Another finding: looking into the actual PAM code, it would seem that the PAM_AUTHTOK item can only be set from PAM modules, not from PAM applications. So, how can PAM applications supply password data to PAM, when PAM modules are configured not to interactively prompt for such information?

Comment: I finally figured out how to do this. Thanks everybody for your help.